# Logout link in JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I created JSF login page which is used for client authentication. I created filter which destroys user session when the user opens page `logout.html`. I want to create simple http link which will be used when it's clicked to redirect user to `logout.html` page. What JSF tag can you recommend for page redirection?

Comment: h:link for pure get request, h:commandButton for preprocessing logic.

Comment: '<h:commandLink>'.To call the action method which performs the session invalidation and redirecting.

Comment: @skuntsel: `h:link` requires a JSF based outcome target, so that doesn't apply.

Comment: By the way, you can achieve the functionality in command button's action method, where you can do the business job, invalidate the session and send redirect. This way logout page is not necessary.

Comment: @Srinivas: OP want a link. He has already done the job in a filter (for some unclear reason, I'd indeed have used a POST action method for that, but that aside, OP may have its own reasons for this ridiculous approach).

Comment: @BalusC didn't notice that is was a non-JSF view.

Comment: @BalusC..Yeah I thought OP wants another approach beside destroying session in the filter.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `<h:outputLink>`.

```
<h:outputLink value="logout.html">Logout</h:outputLink>
```

Do you know that you can even use plain HTML in JSF?

```
<a href="logout.html">Logout</a>
```

Comment: And what about the business method (logging, updating information, etc.)? Or you think OP does it in a Filter?

Comment: @skuntsel: the OP explicitly mentioned that, yes. I recite: *" I created filter which destroys user session when the user opens page logout.html"*. Or are you new to filters as well? Note: it's indeed the wrong approach for the particular functional requirement.

Comment: Not actually. I would only want to stress out that this approach is a bit odd.